# How can I select text over two different JTextField's?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Lets say I have this code:

```
  public static void main(final String [] args)
  {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display Keyword Panel");
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());


    JTextField text1 = new JTextField("This is the first text field");
    text1.setBorder(null);
    text1.setOpaque(false);
    text1.setEditable(false);

    JTextField text2 = new JTextField("This is the second text field");
    text2.setBorder(null);
    text2.setOpaque(false);
    text2.setEditable(false);

    panel.add(text1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(text2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setLocation(450, 400);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
```

I would like to select text over both text1 and text2 fields so that I can copy them both at the same time.  But when I run the application I can only select the text from 1 text field at a time.  How can I make it so that I can select text over all of the text fields that I might have in my program?

Comment: Good question, but I honestly don't believe it is possible using the standard components.

Comment: Are you talking about, when you select a certain range of text in one field - you want that selection range to be applied to all other fields?

Comment: @izuriel no, I would like the two fields to act as if they were all one text field, where I can select text intermittently between the two without having to worry about the bounds of where one text field stops/ends getting in the way.

Comment: Eng.Fouad's answer solved that, if I'm understanding properly then. I did much the same thing as him (he beat me to the answer) and when I hit the copy button it pulled both pieces of text - that's quite simple really.

Comment: @izuriel yea but the problem is in my application it really doesn't make sense to have a copy button anywhere near the text.  I think the problem is I just can't do want I want to do in this situation.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a button, it's the functionality. If you change the function of "Ctrl-C", "Ctrl-X", and "Ctrl-V" in all of your text fields and implement the proper functionality you should be good to go. I'll post a tad bit of code that helped me with special copy/pasting in a project of mine.

Comment: Ok sweet thank you very much, I didn't even think about changing the Ctrl-C, Ctrl-X functionality

Comment: After looking at it (which I haven't done in a while) it's not really relevant to post the code. However, you should look at the inherited `paste()`, `copy()`, and `cut()` methods in `JTextField`.

Comment: I posted an answer for the information and gave an example of creating your own KeyBinding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about making a `JButton` to copy the concatenation of both `JTextField`'s?

For example:

```
btn.setActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection strsel = new java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection(textField1.getText() + textField2.getText());
        java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard clbrd = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clbrd.setContents(strsel, strsel);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that [getSelectedText(](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getSelectedText%28%29)) can do that

[image]

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CaretPositionTest {

    public CaretPositionTest() {
        final JTextField textField = new JTextField("0123456789");
        final JTextField textField1 = new JTextField("0123456789");
        textField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textField1.setText(textField.getSelectedText());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(textField);
        p.add(textField1);
        JButton b;
        p.add(b = new JButton(new AbstractAction("0->5") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.select(5, textField.getText().length());
                textField.setCaretPosition(5);
                textField.moveCaretPosition(textField.getText().length());
            }
        }));
        b.setFocusable(false);
        p.add(b = new JButton(new AbstractAction("5->0") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField.setCaretPosition(5);
                textField.moveCaretPosition(0);
            }
        }));
        b.setFocusable(false);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CaretPositionTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as an answer:

You can look into changing the functionality in `JTextComponent`s `copy()`, `paste()`, and `cut()` methods to alter the way they work for that component.

The downside of this approach, is if you change the way `copy()` works - the user will never the results they expect when trying to copy a selection from a single `JTextField`. The way to solve this problem is implement a new KeyBinding for the component. Here is an example, replacing the "Copy" button with a a "Ctrl-G" KeyBinding.

```
public class Test {
    public static JTextField text1 = new JTextField("This is the first text field");
    public static JTextField text2 = new JTextField("This is the second text field");

    public static void main(final String [] args)
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display Keyword Panel");
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        text1.setBorder(null);
        text1.setOpaque(false);
        text1.setEditable(false);

        text2.setBorder(null);
        text2.setOpaque(false);
        text2.setEditable(false);

        text1.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('G', KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "copyAll");
        text1.getActionMap().put("copyAll", new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
                s.append(text1.getText()).append("\n").append(text2.getText());
                System.out.println(s.toString());
            }
        });

        panel.add(text1);
        panel.add(text2);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setLocation(450, 400);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. But you could add a hotkey listener programatically that could append all the text and add it to the clipboard.

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=82
http://blogs.oracle.com/JavaFundamentals/entry/transferring_text_through_the_clipboard

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a JTable instead of JTextFields?

```
final JTable table = new JTable(2,1);
table.setValueAt("This is the first text field", 0, 0);
table.setValueAt("This is the second text field", 1, 0);
```

A JTable will allow you to select and copy from multiple cells.